# Using LIKE to search for Date with year and month only

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I want to filter my table to show records by month so i make a textboxes for the user input. Now i dont know if my query is correct. I dont have any error but also doesnt have any results. I use LIKE because i dont have specific day provided. Can someone suggest a better way?

[image]

[image]

```
ConnectToDatabase conn = null;
conn = ConnectToDatabase.getConnectionToDatabase(); 
String query = "Select * from inventoryreport where InDate LIKE "+txtYear.getText()+""+ txtMonth.getText()+"";
conn.setPreparedStatement(conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query));
conn.setResultSet(conn.getPreparedStatement().executeQuery());
        java.sql.ResultSetMetaData metaData = conn.getResultSet().getMetaData();
        int columns = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
            columnNames.addElement(metaData.getColumnName(i));
        }
```

Comment: You must use the `PreparedStatement` properly to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Your query parses to something like `SELECT * FROM inventoryreport WHERE InDate LIKE 201403` is that what you want?

Comment: There is no need to use `LIKE` if the column is a *proper* DATE/DATETIME type. Instead, simply compare `x >= startOfPeriod && x < endOfPeriod` (while date-specific SQL functions can be used, I generally use a date range approach).

Comment: What type iss your `InDate` column?

Comment: @user2864740 can you be more specific because im just a noob and i dont know much about that.

Comment: @fge Date if im not mistaken 2013-03-19

Comment: Then don't use "like" or something like that for dates; as @user2864740 rightly mentions, you should use a range (for instance `between`). Failing to do that means your query will be unable to use the index on this column (if any).

Comment: should i still use the textboxes? how can i put the textboxes value to put at the startOfPeriod and endOfPeriod?

Comment: You just grab the values of your text boxes as they exist now and use code to build the start and end of the period to use in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIKE it's wrong choise becouse your db doesn't use index and will be slow (and doesn't work).
The query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM inventoryreport WHERE YEAR(Date_column) = 2014 AND MONTH(Date_column) = 3;
```

So your code is:

```
String query = "Select * from inventoryreport where YEAR(InDate) = " +txtYear.getText()+" AND MONTH(InDate) = "+ txtMonth.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a small mistake in the date format:

```
Your format : YYYYMM (no seperation symbol)
Right format: YYYY-MM-DD (with a '-' to seperate)
```

I think

```
String query = "Select * from inventoryreport where InDate LIKE "+txtYear.getText()+"-"+ txtMonth.getText()+"-00";
```

should fix it, if your database only includes monthly exact values.

Otherwise you should use

```
Select * from inventoryreport where InDate BETWEEN '2014-03-18' AND '2014-03-20'
```

Comment: what if 2014-03-18 is not static and needs to be user defined with no day, month and year only?

Comment: you just have to do it like you did in your example: String query = "Select * from inventoryreport where InDate between "+txtYear.getText()+"-"+ txtMonth.getText()+"-01" and "+txtYear.getText()+"-"+ (new Integer(txtMonth.getText()).intValue() + 1 )+"-01";

Comment: Code in previuos comment doesn't work if txtMonth = 12.

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query can take advantage of indexes when a column in not surrounded by a function.  The following `where` clause would allow the use of indexes:

```
SELECT *
FROM inventoryreport
WHERE Date_Column >= str_to_date(concat_ws('-', txtYear.getText(), txtMonth.getText(), '01'), '%Y-%m-%d') and
      Date_Column < adddate(str_to_date(concat_ws('-', txtYear.getText(), txtMonth.getText(), '01'), '%Y-%m-%d'), interal 1 month)
```

Although more complicated, all the manipulations are on constants, so the query engine can still take advantage of an index on `Date_Column`.